# PopUp after input validation and submit Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, popup

I have the following simple form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="minimum" class="barrier">
  <section class="col col-5">
    <label class="label">Minimum Item</label>
        <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-append fa fa-minus-square"></i>
            <input type="text" name="minimum" autocomplete="off">
        </label>
</section>
<button type="submit" id="myBtn" name="create" class="btn btn-danger">Create</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modall">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <center>
            <div class="modall-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Please Wait while Processing.</p>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the javascript :

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    var setok = document.getElementById("setok");
    if (typeof setok !== "undefined" && element.value == '') {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

the validation form does work perfectly and cannot be submitted until user fill it with correct condition, however after i click the submit button, the popup doesn't show up

here is my validation script :

```
$(function()
            {
                // Validation
                $("#form").validate(
                {                   
                    // Rules for form validation
                    rules:
                    {
                        minimum:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages:
                    {
                        minimum:
                        {
                            required: 'Please Enter only digits!',
                            digits: 'Please Enter only digits!'
                        }
                    },                  

                    errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                    {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    }
                });
            });
```

the thing that i want to do is if i click the button the popup will show up after the validation

Comment: What is the reason you want to use a popup?

Comment: show the users,that the data has been processed, quite useless right? ikr, but with this i can learn much more about javascript

Comment: You've to mark the form as posted at the server, because the page is reloaded after the submission. Ex. add a hidden field to the form when the response is for the POST. Then check the existense of that field in JS, and if it exists, show the pop-up.

Comment: if then the popup will show a little bit before the page reloaded because i make a delay before submitting data to database, even on GET method the popup still doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the button click pop-up event to jQuery validate `submitHandler` method :

```js
    $(function() {
        // Validation
        $("#form").validate({
            // Rules for form validation
            rules: {
                minimum: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                minimum: {
                    required: 'Please Enter only digits!',
                    digits: 'Please Enter only digits!'
                }
            },

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            },

            submitHandler: function() {
                var setok = document.getElementById("setok");
                if (typeof setok !== "undefined" && element.value == '') {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This way the pop-up will shows up after the validation is passed.

Comment: hahaha, sorry it does work, i just realized `element.value == '' ` is not defined

Comment: 1 more the pop-up does show up but the system doesn't submit it to the database it just stuck on the popup and doesn't continue the POST

Comment: nevermind done with `$form.submit();` after the `modal.style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the buttons type to `button`. Now the button will not submit the form. Instead you can run some JS to submit the form when you click the button. You can do that in vanilla JS, jQuery or whatever.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Retreive the data from the form..
  //NOTE: you can implement your popup instead of the alert
  myFakeRequest()
  .then( response => alert(response) )
  .catch( error => alert( error ) )
});

// this just simulates a request delaythat fails half the time
function myFakeRequest() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => {
    window.setTimeout( () => {
    if( Math.random() > 0.5 )
      resolve( 'YAY, successfull request' );
    else
      reject( 'Oh no... The request didn\'t work' );
    }, 1000 )
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="myBtn" name="create" class="btn btn-danger">Create</button>
```